# Magento 2: Product Detail Page Image Not Loading

Tags: magento2

In back end & front end product image is reflecting but on product detail page image are not showing its just loading. I'm done with reindexing, cache clear and resizing the image but no use of it facing the same issue. screenshot here for reference https://prnt.sc/owuqlx. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: you are using porto theme? and backend image availalbe?

Comment: Yes its a porto theme and some default images are available.

Comment: inspect the image element and your console , see if there are any js errors . Also  and copy paste the image url in browser, see it's loading in there.

Comment: i have same issue comed when i have galery.phtml file code change after it working good

Comment: @divyar you have solved above issue?

Comment: @Rakesh Donga can u guide me how to change gallery.phtml file code because am new to magento.

Comment: @divyar check this file: app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\gallery.phtml